# Android Activities are kept in memory, no listeners or references

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, heap-memory, android-actionbaractivity

I have 2 activities (let's say A and B). When i press a button on A, i start an instance of B via StartActivity. When i go back to A, and press the button again, B is still in memory and it will load in a new instance of B, on top of the old one. This goes on until i run out of memory, the old activities are not cleaned up by the garbage collector..

My activity does not have listeners or something that could keep it in memory. I call finish, and i do understand that activities are cleared by android, and not by me. However, the activities are NOT cleared by android, even on low memory..

Why does this happen?

edit:

code where i call finish(Activity B): (typed in csharp, monoandroid, xamarin)

```
    void GoBack()
    {
        if (MadeChanges) {
            Helpers.Dialogs.Show (this,
                null,
                Resources.GetString(Resource.String.dialogitemnotsaved),
                new Helpers.Dialogs.Button (
                    Resources.GetString(global::Android.Resource.String.Yes),
                    () => {
                        Finish ();
                        AnimationHelper.FinishActivityAnimation (this);
                    }
                ),
                new Helpers.Dialogs.Button (
                    Resources.GetString(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel),
                    null
                )
            );
        } else {
            Finish ();
            AnimationHelper.FinishActivityAnimation (this);
        }
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {
        GoBack ();
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
        case global::Android.Resource.Id.Home:

            GoBack ();
            return true;
        default:
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

how do i open activity B from activity A :

```
            Intent intent = new Intent (Activity, typeof(ActivityB));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            this.StartActivityForResult (intent, REFRESH);
            AnimationHelper.StartActivityAnimation (this.Activity);
```

Comment: Show your code of where you are calling finish();

Comment: please, post your code.

Comment: and the code of how i open the activity

Comment: If the garbage collector isn't recovering the memory for Activity B, it means that there is something holding a reference to it which is still alive (ie: not garbage). There are tools (like MAT and others) that can help you find the object that contains a reference to Activity B.